# What characters to limit when user enters an email?

Tags: email

I have a backend that does not support emoji characters in all of its fields, so I want to block them directly in the frontend application. I'm in the register section, and I want to limit the possible characters for the email field.
I know that [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4) specifies that many particularities can be found in those addresses, including special characters. Even emoji can be put there ([link](https://medium.com/@zackbloom/i-have-a-unicode-email-address-fbecd630ec12)).

I'm using a whitelist to implement this block.

What character should I whitelist to support the common emails without falling into whitelisting every characters supported by email addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vast majority (probably over 99%) of the email addresses still use the pre-2012 rules described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local-part):

> The local-part of the email address may use any of these ASCII characters:
>
> - uppercase and lowercase Latin letters `A` to `Z` and `a` to `z`;
> - digits `0` to `9`;
> - printable characters others than letters and digit `` !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~ ``;
> - dot `.`, provided that it is not the first or last character unless quoted, and provided also that it does not appear consecutively unless quoted (e.g. John..Doe@example.com is not allowed but "John..Doe"@example.com is allowed);

So for starters, you can whitelist all ASCII characters; if you feel a little more fancy, you can use a regular expression, e.g. one of those listed [here](https://emailregex.com/).

The HTML element `input` with type `email`, which is often used in web forms, uses [the following regex for validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email#Validation):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$
```

Yes, this does mean that letters diacritical marks like @JörgMittag's `ö` cannot be used: see [this Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/8YOJIs/1). Whether it's worth expanding the regex/character validation to non-ASCII characters depends on your user base. I see you're from Canada; there might be French-speaking users with accented letters in their names and email addresses. If those really need to be supported, check which characters your backend supports (e.g. all [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) characters) and just whitelist those.

Comment: FYI, whitelisting ASCII would make it impossible for me to enter my email address.

Comment: This is good, but please suggest that + is allowed.  It's becoming more common as people realise that they can use it to make unique email addresses for different services and track what services end up spamming them.

Comment: `+` is both in the Wikipedia quote as in the listed regex already ...